# How to allow only "numbers","-" and "()" using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to do phone number validation using JavaScript.
I have already done validation for numbers as follows,

```
  
var filter =/^[0-9]+$/
```

But now I have to also allow hyphen and "()".
Please provide me a way for the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
/^[0-9()-]+$/
```

Notes:

- Parenthesis have no special meaning in a character set
- If you start, or end, with a minus-sign, it is not interpreted as a range, but as the minus-character itself